# Flexigrid built with jquery: does it support right click row functionality?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flexigrid

Flexigrid is awesome but does anyone know if it supports a right click event on a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time I've seen that plugin - very nice, although maybe a bit too rich for me. I use [dataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)

I don't see why you wouldn't be able to add your own click handler to the row. After all they are just standard `<tr>/<td>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it does but you I think [jgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) I think does... I really got to switch to that ;^ )